# I want to see comments which has been added just now

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
 
//At first useEffect, upload all post to posts by setPosts function

// A comment is added and submitted to backend
.then((response) => {
console.log(response.data);
console.log(response.data._id);
for (let i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
  if (posts[i]._id === response.data._id) {
    console.log(posts[i]);
    setPosts({...posts,posts[i].comments:response.data.comments,});  //Find post and revise comments 
                                                                       part.
  }
}
})
```

This is summary of my code. When I add a comment, I want to see this comment immediately. But, in order to see this new comment, I must reload webpage. When I submit new comment to backend, I can see whole comments. So I think, copy new comments part to old comments part by

```
setPosts({...posts,posts[i].comments:response.data.comments,});
```

this code. But, it didn't works.... Please let me know which part is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is: Your `posts` is an array, not an object.

The easiest way to change your code I can think of is updating the part in the `if` condition to mutating the `posts[i]` with the new `comments`

```
for (let i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
  if (posts[i]._id === response.data._id) {
    console.log(posts[i]);
    posts[i].comments = response.data.comments;
    setPosts(posts); 
  }
}
```

We can use `map` to prevent mutating data

```
setPosts(posts.map(post => {
  if (posts[i]._id !== response.data._id) return post;
  return {...post, comments: response.data.comments};
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to append the comment on existing post id. You need to do like this:

```
setPosts([
  ...posts,
  posts[i]:{ <- copy all previous data of post[i]
   ...post[i],
   comments:{...copy all previous comment of post[i]
    ...post[i].comments,
    ...response.data.comments
}}]);
```